# What do we mean by functional context in web services

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, soa

What do we mean by "**functional context**" in web services .

> Each service is assigned its own distinct functional context and is
>   comprised of a set of capabilities related to this context

Answer (score 0):

In short do one thing and do it well, sort of. Typically in SOA you would have lots of different services each dealing with its own context. For example in a sales system you might have a customer, sales rep and orders service. In a banking architecture you could have customers, products, financial instruments and transaction(debit,credit) services.

One of the interesting capabilities of SOA is that once you have lots of small different services you can start to add functionality the architecture by orchestration of other services.  Permit me to use an analogy here. Start thinking of services as lego blocks. They are one piece, one shape and nothing more. You can create a house, a car or anything else with the blocks.

So the functional context is the subject/target of the service. For example in banking we would have a customer service. The capabilities of the customer service means that we have operations relating to that service only. For example create customers, find a list of customers by area, update details etc. YOu would never create a new financial instrument via the customer service.

The idea is to divide all your objects in the problem domain into their own context and develop the capabilities for these object in that context.

One issue that can arise from not sticking to this design pattern is that you have end up with services that have strange operations such as having a customer with a create financial instrument operation. This is incorrect as the customer might be associated with a financial instrument(their saving account, credit card etc) but it is not the owner of the instrument.

Basically all it is saying is that if you create a service it should deal with one area of concern only, and only have operations relating to this concern.

Keep in mind there is nothing to tell you what these contexts are. This is part of the design process you decide on the context.